# Path and PATH environment vars

Tags: environment-variables

I just found out that me system (Windows 8.1) has two different path variables which differ in capitalization (PATH - user variable, Path - system var). I did not notice it before but I have a vague feeling that I have done something wrong when messing with environment variables. Google is of no use because it is case-insensitive.
My question is: Is it an intended by the system or not? Do I have to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, no need to fix. In Windows, environment variable names are case-insensitive.

You can see it if you do:

```
echo %PATH%
```

in cmd prompt. It will display the combination of both values.